# Inline math within \newcommand using Pandoc

Tags: macros, pandoc, inline

I'm trying to define a new command as a shortcut for typing arrows in textmode. This requires to use inline math within the command's definition, since I'd like this to work with more kinds of arrows than just `\textrightarrow`.

Problem is, this affects weirdly the formatting of the text put after the command. Here is a MWE :

```
\newcommand{\ra}{$\rightarrow$}
**hello** \ra *world*  
**hello** $\rightarrow$ *world*  
*hello* \ra **world**  
*hello* $\rightarrow$ **world**
```

[image]

As you can see, italic and bold emphasis are both ignored, and the space after the arrow is removed. Additionally, it seems like the closing `**` on the 3rd line is still recognised, causing some kind of shift in the markup on the 4th line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, you need to place `{}` (or even a `\` as a *control space*) right after your customized command (within the text),

```
\newcommand{\ra}{$\rightarrow$}

**hello** \ra{} *world*  
**hello** $\rightarrow$ *world*  
*hello* \ra{} **world**  
*hello* $\rightarrow$ **world**
```

And it will yield as follows

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I think I might still post an issue on GitHub though, since in LaTeX it works fine without braces.